# customizing Django UserCreationForm so that I create the username from lastname and firstname, not the user entering it?

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I want to modify my UserCreationForm so that when users request to sign up to my site they get given a username of last_name+'.'+first_name.

my django forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
        exclude = ['username', ]
```

So I have excluded the username from the actual form:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {% for field in form %}
   <p>
     {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
     {{ field }}
     {% if field.help_text %}
       <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
     {% endif %}
     {% for error in field.errors %}
       <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
     {% endfor %}
   </p>
 {% endfor %}
 <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

and in my views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
```

*I have tried putting in form.save() here and then trying to get cleaned_data first_name.last_name = username, but it does not work*

```
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            #username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            username = firstname+'.'+lastname

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)

            user.is_active = False

            user.save()
            return render(request, 'registration/signedup.html', {'user': user})

        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form, 'invalid': 'Please try again.'})

    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: any errors are you getting?

Comment: my username is Nonetype at: 

username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

Comment: It seems to me that you need to do form.save() to get the form.cleaned_data out - but you cant save form as username is None - so i need to somehow edit form_save() but I dont know what to do

Comment: what is the problem now?? obviously username will be none as you have excluded the field from the form

Comment: I want username to not be entered, but for the first_name and last_name to be entered in the form. Then I want the username to be automatically assigned to last_name.firstname. For example, John Smith requests access through this form. He enters John into the first_name box, and Smith into the last_name box, then his passwords and email. Then his username automatically becomes smith.john.  The problem is you seem to need the username value to save the form, which is how you get out the first_name and last_name values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the `UserCreationForm` on init checks if the User model `USERNAME_FIELD` attribute exists in the forms fields so you don't want to exclude the `username` attribute unless you've selected another field to be your `USERNAME_FIELD`.

If you want to use username as the USERNAME_FIELD but you don't want it shown on the front end, you can set it as hidden in your html using the template syntax like `{{ form.username.as_hidden }}`

You can then override the `save` method for the `SignUpForm`, this will allow you to do any post processing once the form is valid.

You also don't need to add `password1` and `password2` to the fields because they're inherited.

You should set the `first_name` and `last_name` to be required if you plan on setting the `username` attribute to be the combined value of the 2 otherwise the code i've provided below won't work when users DON'T enter their first_name and last_name.

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.username = '{}.{}'.format(
            self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        )
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```